# login screen freezes

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, login, sddm

I recently installed Ubuntu and when I boot the system or try to login from suspend state the username and password fields gets kind of hang. It takes anywhere from 10 secs to 1 min before it allows me to type my credentials. Thinking this is a Gnome issue I installed Kubuntu, Xubuntu but the same issue.

On doing some reading I found a article in Arch Wiki which appears to be similar to my issue (3.2 - Long load time before SDDM shows the greeter)[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SDDM#Long_load_time_before_SDDM_shows_the_greeter)

It is apparently related to low entropy pool and they had suggested some Random generation suggestions. But I am still a newbie in Linux and I did not completely understand what needs to be done.

Please suggest if anyone had faced the same issue and what is the workaround.

Thank you

Comment: This all sounds highly unusual and I'm 99.99% sure it has nothing to do with the entropy pool. What you describe could be down to problems with DNS resolution however I've no idea why your login manager could be polling DNS. Please upload `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/sddm.log` to e.g. pastebin.com with a 24h expiration time.

Comment: Here is the pastebin link for /var/log/Xorg.0.log: https://pastebin.com/ZhCVNGCJ. In my /var/log folder there is no sddm.log file. Thanks